# How to write out table when using input from scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I wrote code to make a table with random columns and rows and for each position in table, program asks user to write what is inside. For input I used scanner. My question is, how do I print out the table with users input? Can you explain how it is done and why? Thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int row = (int)(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
    int column =(int)(Math.random() * 5 + 1);

    String[][] table = new String [row][column];

    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

    //String word = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {

            System.out.print("Write a name of a fruit: ");
            String word = read.next();
```

Comment: Do you want a specific output format? Otherwise, `Arrays.deepToString(table)` will return a `String` representation of your table, see [here](https://ideone.com/TTeoIC) for an example.

Comment: Note that you don't fill the table with the user inputs in the code extract you posted, which you will obviously need to do before you print it.

Comment: Yes I would like to use System.out.println(). Where do I put it in my code? Do I have to write something more to use it?

Comment: `System.out.println()` will print a whole line, so you need to pass it a row of your table. Do you need to do something with the data once it's printed? If not, you don't actually need to manage a `String[][] table`, it would be enough to fill a `String[] row` which you would print once you've scanned a whole row. And to transform a `String[]` into a `String` which you will be able to pass `System.out.println` I suggest you look into [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take user inputs and store them in your table first

Change your code to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print("Write a name of a fruit: ");
        String word = read.nextLine();
        table[i][j] = word;
    }
}
```

After this, If you wish to print the user given fruit names in the table format, you should add the following code

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(" | " + table[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.print(" |");
    System.out.println();
}
```

What we are doing here is looping through the columns for each row. When we reach the end of the column, we print a new line so the next row gets printed in a new line. I added `|` (pipe) to show the boundary between each column.

The output will look something like this for a 2X2 table:

```
 | Mango | Raspberry |
 | Strawberry | Apple |
```

***Note:*** You can use your initial for-loops to display the values as well. But I chose to create another set of loops for clear understanding.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Good explanation, I understand now how it is done.